# Need to copy files to existing directory and remove files already there with the same name but different extension

Tags: command-line, scripting, find, file-copy

**EDIT:** Total rewrite of question for clarity.

I have a directory tree (**new**) with a bunch of files of with an extension of  `.new`. I have an identical tree (**old**) where many of the files have names identical to those in the **new** tree except that the extension is `.old`. I would like to copy all of the `.new` files from the **new** directory tree into the **old** directory tree which contains the `.old` files. As a file with a `.new` extension is written into the **old** directory tree, I would like to delete any file with the same name but a `.old` extension.

So, if in the **new** directory tree, there is a file named `new/foo/bar/file.new`, it will be copied to the **old** directory tree as `old/foo/bar/file.new` and then the file `old/foo/bar/file.old` will be deleted if it exits.

**EDIT #1**

This answer was hashed out below (using the old question that had extraneous background information that was confusing). See the actual solution that I worked out below as one of the answers.

Comment: I have not idea how to do that using bash commands only, but you could write a shell script (or even a one liner) around find, basename and unique.  However the most practical solutions seems to be to run the conversion step (so that dir B has all the MP3 files and only the MP3 files), then delete dir A and rename (`mv`) dir B to dir A.

Comment: The shell script is what I'm looking for (I don't really think there's a significant difference between a shell script and something for the command line), so I updated the problem to include scripts. Just deleting A and moving B will not verify that every flac in A was converted.

Comment: What do you have thus far?

Comment: Nothing really.

Comment: @Pinyaka - I've deleted my answer, please clean up this Q, it's still unclear what you're asking. You want Bash, but have a method for doing the conversion,s it's a Python script that you could probably just addd a single `rm flacfile`  after the conversion process is done. You've accepted an answer that doesn't actually solve your problem. I'm not being sour grapes I promise you, I only mean this in a constructive way.

Comment: @Pinyaka - Ask terdon or anyone else, it's not my way to be mean spirited about things such as this, sorry if it came across that way, but it's a bit frustrating to offer help and get pulled in different directions without a clear outline of what you're ultimately after.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was the final answer that got hashed out in the comments for terdons answer.

```
cd new
for i in */*/*.new; do cp "$i" "path/to/old/${i}" && rm "path/to/old/${i//new/old}"; done
```

Answer (score 6):

The basic approach would be to run this from the directory containing the mp3 files:

```
for i in *.mp3; do cp "$i" /path/to/flac/ && rm path/to/flac/"${i%.*}".flac; done
```

This goes through all files whose name ends in `.mp3`, copies each to `/path/to/flac/` which should be the directory containing the flac files and *if the copy was successful*, deletes the corresponding `.flac` file. The trick is using the shell's [string manipulation](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html) capabilities, `${i%.*}` will remove the extension so `rm ${i%.*}.flac` will delete the file that has the same name as the current mp3 file but a `.flac` extension.

To illustrate:

```
$ foo='abc.def'
$ echo ${foo%.*}
abc
```

Comment: I failed to mention in my example that the mp3 and flac directories are actually identical directory trees, so just using that for statement won't capture them. I'm going to mark the question as answered because you actually did answer the question that I asked, but I wonder if there's some way to make your one-liner to the same thing with a bunch of subdirectories.

Comment: @Pinyaka you could use the globstar option for recursive globbing. Set it with `shopt -s globstar`, and then you can use `for f in ./**/*.mp3; ...; done`.

Comment: I tried using the globstar mentioned above, but got a "bad substitution error. I still had the globstar option enabled when this command worked for me: `for i in */*/*.mp3; do cp "$i" "path/to/flac/$i" && rm "/path/to/flac/${i//mp3/flac}";done`